# What is meant by BCD16

Tags: encoding, bcd

I'm writing an Ama file generating simulator. In the Ama specifications, it gives the number of bytes(not bits) for a field as BCD16, BCD12 etc(BCD{a number}).

For fields with BCD16 the actual length is 8 bytes. Can anyone please tell me what that BCD16 means ? 
I know BCD is Binary coded decimal but don't understand what BCD16 means.

Comment: Note that the actual length for BDC16 is _two_ bytes, not eight, and the number _does_ represent the number of bits used. BCD values are collections of 4-bit integers, with BCD8 containing two, BCD12 containing three, BCD16 containing four, etc. etc.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a 2-byte (16-bit) BCD encoding. See [here](http://www.fsdeveloper.com/wiki/index.php?title=Variables_-_Formats_-_Encoding_-_Binary#BCD16_-_2_BYTES).

> This is 2 bytes and can store a 4 digit BDC16 encoded number, with one
>   BCD digit stored in each half byte, (aka nibble).
>
> Example - 0011-0110 0010-0101 is 3-6 2-5 which is 3x100 + 6x10 + 2x1 +
>   5x0.1 = 362.5

Comment: Could you please tell me what's meant by BCD12 ?

Comment: I would guess at 1.5 bytes storage. i.e. 3 digits ?

Answer (score 0):

BCD is a [Binary-Coded Decimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal), using [nibbles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nibble) (four bit numbers, encoding 0 through 8) to represent digits.

Real world computing only uses BCD8 (two numbers per byte) and  BCD16 (four numbers per short), and can in rare cases use *multiples of* BCD12 (six numbers per short). You'll never see just a single BCD12, because storing single BCD12 numbers would waste bits, whereas the whole point of using BCD is to make optimal use of whatever memory is available.

Also note: there is no BCD1 through BCD7, because those can't store two nibbles. And, while BCD encoding with more than 16 bits is *possible*, you don't, because at that point you're working on hardware with 32 bit datatypes and you can just work *using bytes* instead of having to cleverly compress data into nibbles.

Answer (score -1):

I think after talking with a senior I found a definition.

BCD{x} means, for a single digit it takes x bits. 
With that ,if it is BCD3, it would take three bits to represent a single digit. Of-course with that we cannot represent every combination.But we can represent some very large values.

Eg: In BCD1 we can represent- 11111111 using one byte.

This is what I found. If there is something wrong with the definitions, please correct me.